# Show that $z\in\mathbb{C}$ satisfying $\arg\Big(\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\Big)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is a circle

Tags: complex-numbers, circles

> Show that the complex number $z$ satisfying the condition $\arg\Big(\dfrac{z-1}{z+1}\Big)=\dfrac{\pi}{4}$ is a circle

I can prove it by expressing $z=x+iy$,
$$
\arg\Big(\frac{x-1+iy}{x+1+iy}\Big)=\arg(x-1+iy)-\arg(x+1+iy)=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
1=\frac{\frac{y}{x-1}-\frac{y}{x+1}}{1+\frac{y^2}{x^2-1}}=\frac{xy+y-xy+y}{x^2-1+y^2}\implies x^2-1+y^2=2y\\\implies x^2+y^2-2y-1=0
$$
But can I show that using geometry and the concept of Apollonius circle ?

Comment: Just a remark: as far as I remember  from middle-school geometry, the answer is only a circular arc.

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1609945/show-that-argz-1-argz1-pi-4?rq=1) is a related link.....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

${\rm arg}\left(\frac{z-1}{z+1}\right)$ is a measure of the angle between $\overrightarrow{AM}$ and $\overrightarrow{BM}$, where $A$ has affix $-1$ and $B$ has affix $1$. Find one point $M_0$ verifying this equation which is not $A$ or $B$. The circumcircle of triangle $M_0AB$, excluding the arc between $A$ and $B$, is the solution, because if $\Omega$ is its center, for every $M$ on this circle, the angle between $\overrightarrow{AM}$ and $\overrightarrow{BM}$ is half the angle between $\overrightarrow{\Omega A}$ and $\overrightarrow{\Omega B}$, which is $\frac\pi2$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M(z), A(-1)$ and $B(1)$.
$\arg(\frac{z-1}{z+1})=(\overrightarrow{MA},\overrightarrow{MB})=\frac{\pi}{4} [\pi]$ is a circle $\Gamma$ passing through $A$ and $B$ except those 2 points.
How to get this circle: let $\Delta$ the perpendicular bisector of $[AB]$, and choose $T$ a point such that $(\overrightarrow{AB},\overrightarrow{AT})=\frac{\pi}{4}$,  define $\Delta’$ as the line perpendicular to $(AT)$ at $A$ and finally $\Omega=\Delta\bigcap\Delta’$. $\Gamma$ is the circle centered a $\Omega$ passing through $A$ or/and $B$.
$\\$
If $\arg(\frac{z-1}{z+1})=(\overrightarrow{MA},\overrightarrow{MB})=\frac{\pi}{4} [2\pi]$ $\Gamma$ is the arc located in the half plan delimited by $(AB)$ and not containing the point $T$. This method is still valid if we change $\frac{\pi}{4}$ by any value $\theta$